# Fit rotated image inside a container

Tags: flutter

I have container which has a fixed dimention set. Inside that I am adding an image that is rotated 45 degree. What I want to achieve is to fit the image inside the container after rotation. I have attached a screenshot in the below picture. I have tried fitted box but it doesn't work.

In the below Image I want to fit the image within  the circle that it's overlapping by its corner

[image: Screenshot]

here's a sample code to show this issue

```
    Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                // width: 140,
                height: 450,
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Transform(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateZ(pi / 4),
                    child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                      return Image.asset(
                        'assets/arts/woman_avatar.jpeg',
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

This is the output of the above code. & I want to fit the image inside red rectangle after it is rotated.
[image: sample output]

Comment: without your code it really becomes hard to know the context of what you've achieved

Comment: It would be wise to refer us to the circle you are directing us to by adding your code

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with sample code & a more demonstrating screenshot about the issue. @Davis

Answer (score 0):

try to set its width to

> MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4

that is the width of the phone divided by the diagonal length of the square.
also for the height. if it needs to be a bit smaller try to divide with a bigger number(ex 1.5 should work fine)

Comment: I don't thinks it will be a optimal solution and works for all size & dynamic dymensions of image,